# How to deploy a project using oracle 11g XE as backEnd to a Java front end

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, oracle11g

I want to know how to deploy project using Oracle 11g Express Exition as the back end and Java as front end.

I have used Java and MS Access as back end in which I supplied a .mdb file with the project. But I don't know how deployment actually works iF I use oracle as back end and Java as front end.

The IDE I'm using is Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Deploying Oracle 11g Express when comparing to MS Access is like comparing chalk and cheese. They are worlds apart.

Deploying Oracle Express is like installing any other piece of software. You have to chose options and specify passwords (need to record those) when installing Oracle Express.

Usually when deploying (and re-deploying) an application the installation of DB software is usually only done once. If changes need to be made to data in the database then change scripts are the preferred options.

Comment: understood but still confusion... lets suppose i have made simple college management software in java and used oracle as back end. i want to that if i want to give this software to client then the client should also install oracle in there pc or is there some file in oracle that i can bundle with final software. like in ms access we can bundle .mdb file with java setup. i just want to know how i can make final product as a software using oracle as back end.

Comment: As far as I'm aware there is nothing like this with any of the major DBs (Oracle, Sql Server, PostgreSQL, DB2, etc....) All required a DB Server which is not a trivial piece of software to install. It is perhaps possible if you use a 3rd Party installer that installs your software (which may include the Java JRE) and the Oracles Express by feeding the Oracle express installer with known values. Some installers to try are http://izpack.org/, http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/, and http://www.installjammer.com/

Comment: Actually XE does come with a silent install function.  It may not be quite as neat Access but it is there.  After all, installing XE as a local database is a different class from installing an enterprise RAC system.

Comment: what if Im just developing a standalone application using database as oracle. Then does client should install such a huge database for using a simple standalone software? Or for developing standalone software some other database are used ?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is installation in 'Silent Mode' .  Basically you need to edit one of the silent install response templates to provide defaults for the Installer's prompts (Listener ports, SYS passwords, etc).

The process is covered in the [Express Edition documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/install.112/e18803/toc.htm#XEINW125).

Comment: Didn't known this one. Thanks @APC.